# vue 3 with vite - lazy loading with dynamic path problem

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I am using Vue 3 with Vite with VueRouter

```
   let test_Route = 'Test';

   const routes = [
       { path: '/' ,     name:'default' ,component: () => import('@/views/login.vue') },
       { path: '/Test' , name:'Test' ,   component: () => import(`@/views/${test_Route}/login.vue`) }
   ]

console.log(routes)
//--the rest of the routing code
```

the problem is Vue does not import the `Test` component

when log routes - it does not process the template string `@/views/${test_Route}/login.vue` it treats it like its a normal string

so how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Please check my answer there: [Vue lazy loading does not work in Vite as did in Vue-CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112215/vue-lazy-loading-does-not-work-in-vite-as-did-in-vue-cli)

The reason behind this, is to help static analysis to avoid a possible shoot in the foot. So to import your component, the `imports` must start with `./` or `../`.

**All imports must start relative to the importing file.**