# src alias in vite/vue project with @ symbol not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have installed Vue3/TS project with Vite CLI

My vite.config.ts looks like this:

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        },
    },
})
```

Also I add 'paths' property inside tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*", "./dist/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```

With this setup '@' alias works fine with simple component importing.
But in my case, I was needed in dynamic import with template strings:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from '@/store/app'
import { computed, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const store = useStore()
const userRole = store.getUserRole

const component = computed(() => {
    return defineAsyncComponent(
        () => import(`@/components/pages/dashboard/${userRole}.vue`)
    )
})
</script>
```

This sample throw an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '@/components/pages/dashboard/admin.vue'
> at dashboard.vue:14:54

If I replace '@' with dot-notation - it works fine. Need your help)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your alias definition is fine, but you are missing a details about importing **dynamic** assets with Vite. I already explained it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70133246/774432) *(for Vue but we are talking about Vite's behavior here)*.

> With this setup '@' alias works fine with simple component importing.
> But in my case, I was needed in dynamic import with template strings:

> If I replace '@' with dot-notation - it works fine. Need your help)

This is due to Rollup Limitations. All imports **must start relative** to the importing file and import should not start with a variable.

You have to replace the alias (@/) with relative or absolute path `./components` or `/src/components` as you already did:

```
const component = computed(() => {
    return defineAsyncComponent(
        () => import(`./components/pages/dashboard/${userRole}.vue`)
    )
})
```

- Vite [Documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#static-asset-handling)